# Is it a problem to connect a controlled current source in parallel to a voltage source?

Tags: transistors, mosfet, circuit-analysis, amplifier, power-amplifier

Does a similar connection cause conflicts or damage?

[image]

An example of situation in which it's used. I've seen it's common practice in RF to put an inductor (RF Choke) between the drain of a MOSFET and VDD like in the following picture:

[image]

At DC, VDS is set equal to VDD. But between D and S there is a voltage controlled current source, since the MOSFET is biased between gate and source so that it can provide a proper drain current. So, current source in parallel with voltage source.

How can the MOSFET current source react when there is something that forces its voltage? In non-RF class A amplifiers, usually there is a resistor instead of an inductor and so this situation doesn't occur.

Comment: Your logic does not apply, because the inductor does have an impedance at RF frequency AC, just like the resistor would. So there will not be a fixed voltage over the inductor.

Comment: @Justme But at DC it's a short, and the mosfet is acting as a voltage (dc) controlled current source

Comment: In general, a current source can exist in parallel with a voltage source happily and with no contradiction or conflict.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you would expect with a voltage and a current source in parallel, the current is defined by the current source, and voltage is defined by the voltage source.

The RF choke therefore constrains the DC value of the drain voltage to be equal to the supply. The FET causes its average current to flow through the RF choke.

It's at AC where things get interesting. The RF choke now behaves like a current source. We now have two current sources in parallel. The load resistance controls the voltage that the current produces.

At AC, the voltage can swing above and below the supply voltage. If the load had been a resistor, then the FET could have only pulled the voltage below the supply.

Answer (score 0):

In your circuit at DC, think of the MOSFET more like a switch than a current source since at DC you'll mostly be in the triode region. The voltage Vdd squared divided by the drain-source resistance will give you the power dissipated, and you want that to be small enough to not burn out the transistor (when using it like a switch).

It doesn't work like an amplifier until you are at a frequency high enough that the inductor has some impedance.